# Error in SQL Syntax (Uncaught MySQLi sql exception). Tried other answers to no avail

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb, syntax-error

I have a **PHP** file in which I am essentially reading a **SQL** file into an array and setting a variable equal to that and then replacing the word `<DB_PREFIX>` with my `$db_prefix` variable and the just executing the SQL. But then I am receiving an error which seems very vague.

The error message is as follows:

> **Fatal error:** Uncaught *mysqli_sql_exception*: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS chbep_accounts` at line 74 in *C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\install\file.inc.php:74*

Here is my *file.inc.php* line *74*:

```php
$sql_dump = file($sql_dump_file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

$database_prefix = "chbep_";

$sql_dump = str_ireplace('<DB_PREFIX>', $database_prefix, $sql_dump);

foreach($sql_dump as $sql_line){

  $tsl = trim($sql_line);
  if(($sql_line != '') && (substr($tsl, 0, 2) != '--') && (substr($tsl, 0, 1) != '?') && (substr($tsl, 0, 1) != '#')) {

    $query .= $sql_line;
    if(preg_match('/;\s*$/', $sql_line)){

      if((strlen(trim($query)) > 5) && !@mysqli_query($link, $query)){  

        $error_mg[] = mysqli_error($link);
    return false;

      }

      $query = '';

    }

  }

}
```

The `$sql_dump` variable is my custom SQL file which is read into an array using the `file()` function and the variable is set as equal to that, then I am replacing the <DB_PREFIX> with my own `$db_prefix` variable which in this case is *'chbep_'*. Here is my custom SQL file and the line which I am seeing in the error above:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `<DB_PREFIX>accounts`;
```

Additional SQL lines:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `<DB_PREFIX>accounts` (
  `id` smallint(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `last_name` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_name` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `password` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `email` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `profile_photo` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `profile_photo_thumb` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `account_type` enum('owner','mainadmin','admin','hotelowner','agencyowner','regionalmanager','hotelmanager') CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'mainadmin',
  `companies` varchar(1024) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `preferred_language` varchar(2) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `oa_consumer_domain` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `oa_consumer_key` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `oa_consumer_secret` varchar(70) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `oa_date_created` datetime NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_created` datetime NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_lastlogin` datetime NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `registration_code` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET latin1 NULL DEFAULT '',
  `registration_type` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET latin1 NULL DEFAULT '',
  `is_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `room_relocation` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `hotel_relocation` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

Comment: Can you post the part where you think you replace `<DB_PREFIX>`?

Comment: I made a mistake in that area in the question but the error does have the correct prefix

Comment: Have you tried doing `var_dump($query);` just before you execute it, to see what you're actually sending to the DB, in full

Comment: According to the logic of your loop, if your SQL statement spans multiple lines then the lines will be concatenated together without a whitespace

Comment: @KenLee not in mysql, AFAIK. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/drop-table.html

Comment: @RobEyre Yes that is what it appears to be doing, I am a developer working on someone else's project and with this code that the previous developer added it worked until php 7.4.0, but when I changed the PHP version and ran this code it started to break and give this error

Comment: I think we cannot blind guess what is happening. Can you post the part of your code using file() to parse the sql file ? please also show a fragment of the sql file (which contains the drop table line) so that we can further check. In short, please provide a minimum reproducible example. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Did you do the var_dump yet? Then we can see _exactly_ what is being sent to the database server. Just put that line above where you run mysqli_query

Comment: It doesn't look like you copied the quoting correctly in the error message. When MySQL says "near <something>" it puts it in single quotes, not backticks.

Comment: Where in that file is `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `<DB_PREFIX>accounts`;`? Did you make sure that there is no text before the `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `<DB_PREFIX>accounts`;`?

Comment: @Dharman Yes the `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS <DB_PREFIX>accounts;` is the first line

Comment: Make sure the file doesn't have any lines containing multiple queries. You can only execute one query at a time with `mysqli_query()`; you need to use `mysqli_multi_query()` to execute multiple queries in a single call (but I don't recommend using this, as processing the results is more complicated).

Comment: What do you mean the first line? That should be the the start and the end of your SQL.

Comment: Check the file with a hex editor -- I'll bet there's a BOM character at the beginning of the first line.

Comment: @Dharman I think they mean first line of the file.

Comment: @Dharman it's part of a a whole SQL dump file, being read into the PHP line by line.

Comment: @ADyson the `var_dump` returned: ``string(41) "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `chbep_accounts`;"``

Comment: That's 38 characters, not 41

Comment: @Dharman The `var_dump` returned this I am guessing it is 41 with the chbep_ being <DB_PREFIX> instead

Comment: @DataLeo no because it dumps what's actually in $query now, not what was in it before!

Comment: You presumably have some hidden characters. Open the dump file in a text editor like notepad++ and tell it to show all symbols

Comment: Oh then I can not see any extra characters that makes it 41

Comment: Ok, so 38 + 3 bytes for BOM makes it 41.

Comment: I can not provide any more SQL code as it is classified but I might be able to provide a reproducible

Comment: A BOM character may not show in notepad++, but if you open the editor and it says "UTF-8 BOM" as the encoding in the bottom-right corner that'll tell you that there's a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) in your file

Comment: `I can not provide any more SQL code as it is classified`...we really don't need it, I don't think.

Comment: Thanks, so what might be the problem and if it is the unicode character that is causing the problem how do I get rid of it

Comment: You should be able to get rid of it in notepad++ by opening the file, going to the encoding menu, changing the encoding to UTF-8, and saving the file

Comment: The problem is BOM. You can save the file without BOM or if you have no control over the file, strip it in PHP while reading the file.

Comment: Created a reproducible

Comment: Just to ask and re-confirm --- So even you removed the BOM , it still has problems ??

Comment: Thanks guys sorry I wasn't able to change the utf8 bom at once as I didn't know how to in vs code

Comment: Feel free to post it as an answer to be accepted and upvoted

Comment: Nobody will be allowed to post an answer because it has been closed. By the way, we seldom post an answer for such question because it is regarded as not reproducible or was caused by typos.

Comment: I did provide a reproducible but I did not know it was the encoding that was set to UTF-8 BOP so even if you created the files and had the same code you couldn't have reproduced the error unless you specifically changed the encoding to UTF-8 BOP. Thanks guys.

Comment: `you couldn't have reproduced`...which, of course, unfortunately means it's not actually reproducible from the code in the question. The clue was in the var_dump output in the end, since it counts the actual characters, not just the visible ones :-)